# Wait with Read() for Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I wrote a simple console application that should process some tasks in parallel. For this I used Parallel.ForEachlike this:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(_jobs, async job =>
        {
            await job.DoItAsync();
        });
        Console.Read();
```

My application should stop when all tasks in the list _jobs have finished.
However, this works only if I have a "Console.Read()" after the Parallel.
Now the user has to enter a key after the processing has ended. But this is not what I want. I want the app to close automatically after my execution has finished.
But if I remove the Read() statement, my app just exists directly without doing anything.

Any ideas what I need to change here?

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(_jobs.Select(job => job.DoItAsync()));`

Comment: `async job => ...` is an `async void` method, it can await but it is not awaited. Parallel.* and async don't work well together.